# Shuffle string data in python

Tags: python

I have a column with 10 million strings. The characters in the strings need to be rearranged in a certain way.

Original string: `AAA01188P001`

Shuffled string: `188A1A0AP001`

Right now I have a for loop running that takes each string and repositions every letter, but this takes hours to completed. Is there a quicker way to achieve this result?

This is the for loop.

```
for i in range(0, len(OrderProduct)):
    s = list(OrderProduct['OrderProductId'][i])
    a = s[1]
    s[1] = s[7]
    s[7] = a 
    a = s[3]
    s[3] = s[6]
    s[6] = a 
    a = s[2]
    s[2] = s[3]
    s[3] = a 
    a = s[5]
    s[5] = s[0]
    s[0] = a 
    OrderProduct['OrderProductId'][i] = ''.join(s)
```

Comment: what is the logic for shuffling

Comment: Like @Jeril already asked, is this random shuffling or is there a certain logic behind it?

Comment: @Erfan I think *shuffled in a certain way* implies the latter. Agreed with Jeril

Comment: One improvement is that you do not need to convert each string into a list, a string is already a sequence.

Comment: There is logic behind this. 

postition 5 to 7, to the front (0-2)
position 0, to position 3
position 4, to position 4
position 1, to position 5
position 2, to position 6
position 3, to position 7

Comment: something like ''.join([a[5:8], a[0], a[4], a[1],  a[3], a[2], a[8:]])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just reconstruct the string with slices if that logic is consistent?

```
s = OrderProduct['OrderProductId'][i]
new_s = s[5]+s[7]+s[1:2]+s[6]+s[4]+s[0]+s[3]+s[1]
```

or as a format string:

```
new_s = '{}{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(s[5],s[7]...)
```

Edit : +1 for Dave's suggestion of ''.join() the list vs. concatenation.

Comment: ````def transform(s):
    new_s = s[5]+s[7]+s[1:2]+s[6]+s[4]+s[0]+s[3]+s[1]
    return(new_s)````

````order['OrderProductId123'] = order['OrderProductId'].apply(transform)````

This works pretty well and fast

Comment: ^ "".join is much faster than concatenation though?

Answer (score 5):

I made a few performance tests using different methods:

Here are the results I got for 1000000 shuffles:

```
188A1AA0P001 usefString 0.518183742
188A1AA0P001 useMap     1.415851829
188A1AA0P001 useConcat  0.5654986979999999
188A1AA0P001 useFormat  0.800639699
188A1AA0P001 useJoin    0.5488918539999998
```

based on this, a format string with hard coded substrings seems to be the fastest.

Here is the code I used to test:

```
def usefString(s): return f"{s[5:8]}{s[0]}{s[4]}{s[1:4]}{s[8:]}"

posMap = [5,6,7,0,4,1,2,3,8,9,10,11]
def useMap(s): return "".join(map(lambda i:s[i], posMap))

def useConcat(s): return s[5:8]+s[0]+s[4]+s[1:4]+s[8:]

def useFormat(s): return '{}{}{}{}{}'.format(s[5:8],s[0],s[4],s[1:4],s[8:])

def useJoin(s): return "".join([s[5:8],s[0],s[4],s[1:4],s[8:]])

from timeit import timeit
count = 1000000
s = "AAA01188P001"

t = timeit(lambda:usefString(s),number=count)
print(usefString(s),"usefString",t)

t = timeit(lambda:useMap(s),number=count)
print(useMap(s),"useMap",t)

t = timeit(lambda:useConcat(s),number=count)
print(useConcat(s),"useConcat",t)

t = timeit(lambda:useFormat(s),number=count)
print(useFormat(s),"useFormat",t)

t = timeit(lambda:useJoin(s),number=count)
print(useJoin(s),"useJoin",t)
```

**Performance**: *(added by @jezrael)*

```
N = 1000000
OrderProduct = pd.DataFrame({'OrderProductId':['AAA01188P001'] * N})

In [331]: %timeit [f'{s[5:8]}{s[0]}{s[4]}{s[1:4]}{s[8:]}' for s in OrderProduct['OrderProductId']]
527 ms ± 16.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [332]: %timeit [s[5:8]+s[0]+s[4]+s[1:4]+s[8:] for s in OrderProduct['OrderProductId']]
610 ms ± 18.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [333]: %timeit ['{}{}{}{}{}'.format(s[5:8],s[0],s[4],s[1:4],s[8:]) for s in OrderProduct['OrderProductId']]
954 ms ± 76.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [334]: %timeit ["".join([s[5:8],s[0],s[4],s[1:4],s[8:]]) for s in OrderProduct['OrderProductId']]
594 ms ± 10.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to shuffle the strings (no particular logic), you can do that in a several ways:

**Using string_utils:**

```
import string_utils
print string_utils.shuffle("random_string")
```

**Using built-in methods:**

```
import random
str_var = list("shuffle_this_string")
random.shuffle(str_var)
print ''.join(str_var)
```

**Using numpy:**

```
import numpy
str_var = list("shuffle_this_string")
numpy.random.shuffle(str_var)
print ''.join(str_var)
```

---

But if you need to do so with a certain logic (e.g. put each element in a specific position), you can do this:

```
s = 'some_string'
s = ''.join([list(s)[i] for i in [1,6,2,7,9,4,0,8,5,10,3]])
print(s)
```

**Output:**

```
otmrn_sisge
```

If this is still taking too long, you can use multiprocessing. Like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(4) # 4 is the number of workers. usually is set to the number of CPU cores

def shuffle_str(s):
    # do shuffling here, and return


list_of_strings = [...]
list_of_results = p.map(shuffle_str, list_of_strings)
```

Comment: the user need to shuffle using a precise logic.